# Know how to write a mysql update query with trim function in set clause?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, trim

I need to make a update query that can allow me to update in trimming leading '0' in a particular column. I know I can write a select query like this to select trimmed value below:

SELECT TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM SkuCode) FROM MyTable WHERE Id=1;

But how can implement this is in update query. Please help me.

Comment: will there be always a leading 0? and what type is that column?

Comment: Type of column is varchar

Answer (score 0):

if the column is a text or varchar type try

```
UPDATE MyTable set SkuCode = SUBSTRING(SkuCode,2) WHERE Id = 1
```

Comment: Type of column is varchar

Comment: NOTE: the behavior of this SUBSTR function is much different than the OP TRIM function. This SUBSTR expression will "trim" the first character from SkuCode, whatever it is, without regard to whether it's a "0" or not. This will "trim" only one character.

Answer (score 0):

If this SELECT statement is returning the value you want to assign to the skucode column:

```
SELECT t.skucode                        AS current_skucode
     , TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM t.skucode) AS proposed_skucode
  FROM MyTable t 
 WHERE t.id=1 ;
```

Then you can convert that into an UPDATE statement, by replacing **`SELECT ... FROM`** with **`UPDATE`**, and adding a **`SET`** clause before the **`WHERE`** clause, to assign the expression that returns the proposed value for sku code to the sku code column, e.g.

```
UPDATE MyTable t
   SET t.skucode = TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM t.skucode)
 WHERE t.id=1 ;
```